# Update items on page with Ajax to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok so I want to say I'm sorry first off if this has been asked before. I can't seem to find it in the asked questions section though, and I've spent hours looking for what I need.

So to start off with. I'm pulling rows of data from a table off my database -> Products. Then adding them to the cart. I know how to do this in PHP but I'm new to JavaScript and Ajax. I do have my code working where I can  submit one form to add to the database, but it's not working for any after the first one.

I'll include all my code too, but I just need help figuring out how to add each individual item to the cart. It seems simple to me logically, but I can't figure out the correct way to do this and appreciate any help!

Here is my code for the page showing the database products.

```
//*script*//
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {


                $("#FormSubmitAddToCart").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if($("#qtyArea").val()==='0')
                        {
                            alert("Please enter a quantity!");
                            return false;
                        }

                        $("#FormSubmitAddToCart").hide(); //hide submit button
                        $("#LoadingImage").show(); //show loading image

                        var id = 'id='+ $("#idArea").val();
                        var qty = 'qty='+ $("#qtyArea").val(); 
                        var myData = id+'&'+qty;
                        //alert(myData);
                        jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                        url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                        data:myData, //Form variables
                        success:function(response){
                            $("#responds").append(response);
                            $("#idArea").val(''); //empty text field on successful
                            $("#qtyArea").val(''); //empty text field on successful
                            $("#FormSubmitAddToCart").show(); //show submit button
                            $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image

                        },
                        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            $("#FormSubmitAddToCart").show(); //show submit button
                            $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
                        });
                });
    </script>

//*selects products from database*//
<?php
include_once("config.php");

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">
            <div class="del_wrapper">
                '.$row["name"].' - $'.$row["price"].'
                <input type="hidden" id="idArea" value="'.$row["id"].'">
                <input type="number" id="qtyArea" value="0">
                <button id="FormSubmitAddToCart">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </li><br />';
}

?>
```

And my response page is working and posting the first form data to the cart table.

I know I need some kind of loop or way to id what form is being submitted with the button, but not sure how to do this. Any suggestions? And just to let you know, I do secure my stuff after I get it working. Thanks! :D

---

************************ FIXED CODE THAT WORKS BELOW THESE LINES **************************

---

Here is the full update that now works for me.

Script Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[id^=FormSubmitAddToCart]').click(function(){
            // now this is your product id, and now you should
                var p_id= $(this).attr('id').replace('FormSubmitAddToCart-', '');

            // this is  your quantity
                var p_qty = $('#qtyArea-'+p_id).val();

            // + now you know the product id and quantity, so you should handle the rest

                var myData = 'id='+p_id+'&qty='+p_qty;

                alert(myData);
            //  throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");

                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                data:myData, //Form variables
                success:function(response){
                    $("#responds").append(response);
                    $("#idArea").val(''); //empty text field on successful
                    $("#qtyArea").val(''); //empty text field on successful
                    $("#FormSubmitAddToCart").show(); //show submit button
                    $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image

                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    $("#FormSubmitAddToCart").show(); //show submit button
                    $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
                });

            })
        });
    </script>
```

Form Code for submission:

```
<?php
    include_once("config.php");

    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products");
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">
                <div class="del_wrapper">
                    '.$row["name"].' - $'.$row["price"].'

                    <input type="hidden" id="idArea-'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row["id"].'"/>
                    <input type="number" id="qtyArea-'.$row["id"].'" value="0">
                    <button id="FormSubmitAddToCart-'.$row["id"].'">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
            </li><br />';
    }

?>
```

response.php page

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST["qty"]) && ($_POST["qty"] != 0) ) {
    //check $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty

    //sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH Strip tags, encode special characters.
    $MID = "43";
    $ID = $_POST["id"];
    $QTY = $_POST["qty"];

    echo $ID.$QTY;

    // Insert sanitize string in record
    //$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO add_delete_record(content,qty) VALUES('".$contentToSave.",".$QTY."')");

    $insert_row = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO orders(members_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)');
    $insert_row->bind_param('iii', $MID, $ID, $QTY);
    $insert_row->execute();
    $insert_row->close();

    if($insert_row)
    {
         //Record was successfully inserted, respond result back to index page
          $my_id = $mysqli->insert_id; //Get ID of last inserted row from MySQL
          echo '<li id="item_'.$my_id.'">';
          echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$my_id.'">';
          echo '<img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
          echo '</a></div>';
          echo $ID.'-'.$QTY.'</li>';
          $mysqli->close(); //close db connection

    }else{

        //header('HTTP/1.1 500 '.mysql_error()); //display sql errors.. must not output sql errors in live mode.
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
        exit();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: First if all there is a problem at the id you set, because you use the qtyArea and idArea inside a loop, so the id of two elements will be same.

Comment: That's the issue I am running into. I tried to use the products id to add to that button id that way it would be a unique ID like <button id="FormSubmitAddToCart(product id goes here, no parentheses.)">Add to Cart</button>, but I'm not sure what to do after.

Comment: @can you please check the answer

Comment: Hey @AbhisekMalakar, I appreciate you're time and response. I'm going to test this out and get back to you! Looks like I was doing it wrong. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html should looks like this.

```
            <input type="hidden" id="idArea-'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row["id"].'">
                            <input type="number" id="qtyArea-'.$row["id"].'" value="0">

                            // + javascript

                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('[id^=FormSubmitAddToCart]').click(function(){
                                // now this is your product id, and now you should
                                    var p_id= $(this).attr('id').replace('FormSubmitAddToCart-', '');

                               // this is  your quantity
                                    var p_qty = $('#qtyArea-'+p_id).val();

                                    // + now you know the product id and quantity, so you should handle the rest

                                })
                            });
```

Comment: Good sir, your code worked. I only had to tweak a few things on my end and it is glorious! Thank you so much! For anyone who needs to see the full code, I'll edit my question and post it below all of my original stuff. Hopefully it helps you to see it all at once.